# Flutter Align the widget onto the top in ROW

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-layout

I have an issue in ROW that one child has many items so it is large and another child has fewer items so its height is small so the less item is showing in the center of the ROW, so I need it to align to the top inside the ROW, you can have a look at the image.

[image]

Please have a look at my code as well.

```
rowList = Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: mainBodyList,
);
```

**MAIN BODY LIST**

```
  Container(
   width: screenWidth * 0.49,
   child: Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          //width: 200,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    child:
                        /*Image.asset(
                                        'assets/icons/doc_icon.png'),*/
                        Icon(
                      Icons.playlist_add_check,
                      color: AppTheme.primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        _localization.localeString(name),
                        style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.primaryColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: _dynamicListWidget(list),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to set `crossAxisAlignment` as `CrossAxisAlignment.start`

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: mainBodyList,
);
```